# Excel - Screen flicker on screen update

Tags: excel, vba

I've got yet another question from the long serries of 'Stop excel screen from flickering', but I think this one is a bit more tricky.

I've got a client who requires a 'progress' bar on his spreadsheet during macro execution. 
What I've done, is I've a pie chart linked to 2 cells which I adjust based on the progress. For performance, I've disabled `events`, `ScreenUpdating` and changed `calculation to manual`.

Then, once in a while I quickly toggle `ScreenUpdating on and off` to actually update the progress chart. This works like a charm every time I use it (more than 30 projects now).

Recently, the client came back to me with a 'big' problem. Whenever I do the quick toggle to refresh the progress chart, the entire excel screen (including all the items on it)flickers, which drives the guy crazy.

Has anyone got any idea on what could be done with this to keep the chart updating while keeping the front page constantly displayed (the macro jumps between pages) without screen flickering? Something like double buffering or so...

**SOLUTION**

Believe it or not, but I just found a solution. This was so so so easy. In VBA, it's possible to refresh just a specific object, while the remaining screen remains 'locked'. For example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Welcome").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Refresh
```

Thank you everyone for your input.

Comment: Possibly a userform with a progress bar? (or something like a progress bar) so that you do not need to toggle `screenupdating`?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to avoid using forms to achieve this. They are sooo ugly, but I'll keep them as a last resort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to rewrite the macro so that it doesn't "jump between pages" (since it's usually not necessary to `activate` worksheets in order to manipulate their data.  Otherwise, either a user form or the application's `StatusBar` could be used to display a progress bar:

```
Sub StatusBar()
Dim pct As Double
Dim msg as String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 10000 To 1 Step -1
    pct = (10000 - i) / 10000
    msg = Format(pct, "0.0%")  & " complete"
    Application.StatusBar = msg

Next
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is a revised example with UserForm. Note that you will need to add the UserForm module, and at least one Label to it in order to present the information:

```
Sub StatusBar()
Dim pct As Variant
DoEvents
UserForm1.Show vbModeless

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 10000 To 1 Step -1
    pct = (10000 - i) / 10000
    If Int((i / 10000) * 100) = (i / 10000) * 100 Then
        msg = Format(pct, "0%")
        UserForm1.Label1 = msg & " complete"
    End If
Next
UserForm1.Label1 = "Finished!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Problem might be that, depending on how quickly your macro(s) execute, the progress indicator may appear to jump from 0 to 100%. You can do graphical progress bars, too, but the basic idea behind it would be the same, just instead of updating a label value, you'd be changing the size of a textbox with a differing background color, etc.

**Revised per OP comments**

This is how you can "copy" a range from one sheet to another sheet without "copy/paste":

```
Set rng1 = Sheets(1).Rows(12)
Set rng2 = Sheets(2).Rows(1)

rng2.Value = rng1.Value
```

So, you can just define your ranges, and assign the second range to = the first range.

Comment: Thanks for your sugegstion. I generally don't jump if I don't have to. Sadly in this case I'm copying cells between pages and copy / paste only works on active pages, so this isn't.

I also use thae status bar already to show details of the progress. But you know how it is - people like when things shine and move around....

Comment: Instead of copy/paste, you can write the cell values (and formats) directly in the VBA.  `Sheets(2).Cells(1,1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value`, etc... But if you are unable to use the status bar, then a popup userform might work best.

Comment: I wish it was that easy. The script has about 1 - 2 million rows to juggle around during every update session GIS asset management stuff) and copying them cell by cell would take me days. With some additional manupulation, the entire data re-load process takes about 40 minutes with a few variable duration stages in between, so a progress bar helps a lot

Comment: Sheet's do not need to be active to copy/paste from or to.

Comment: You're already "copying" them, though. Writing values directly is faster than copy/paste.  In any case, I updated to include a quick userform with a text-based progress indicator. SHould get you started at least.

Comment: Per @NickSlash you can absolutely copy/paste without Activating the sheets in your VBA. `Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy` and then `Sheets(2).Paste`

Comment: That too, I was thinking of `Range.Copy <destination>` though. eg `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I23").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")`

Comment: @NickSlash yep. Probably OP doesn't want to copy the entire sheet, but that was just an example of how it is done without Activating a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have to investigate that. Pasting ranges never worked for me in the past on inactive pages - used to spend hours trying to find out why do I get blank pages all the time. Simply activating them solved the problem. As for looping across cells, it's sooo much faster for me to copy/paste the entire row compared to going through each cell individually. Excel is definitely optimizing it somehow inside. I'll do some checks and I'll keep you posted. For now, upvoting both your comments for constructive input.

Comment: See my revision for how to work with range/entire row without copy/paste.

Comment: To be honest, this migth actually be what I was looking for! After so many years, I didn't know you can assing ranges to ranges.!

Comment: Hey no problem. I honestly learn something new almost every day :)

Comment: Sadly this has not solved all my problems. Leaving `ScreenUpdating` enabled had a huge impact on performance of the script. I suppose all that's left now is either flicker or a userform... Really disappointing, but hey! They don't have to stare at the screen all the time while this loads.

Comment: Too bad... a form is probably the best way. You can create a small one, and define everything about it except for the progress indicator which will be variable. If you make it small, position it properly, and format it, it shouldn't be too "ugly" and the "progress bar" feature might just be the sort of flair that your client is looking for :)

Comment: Good news, I found a solution! Updated the original question with an answer.